# Ubuntu 10.10 vs 10.04 for a server?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-10.10

Which one is more suitable for a server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 is a LTS (Long-Term Support) release, and so is better suited for use on a server unless you're certain you have requirements that can only be fulfilled by 10.10.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are the "requirements that can only be fulfilled by 10.10"? Any links?

Comment: Newer software than what's in 10.04.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: LTS 10.04 was released on April 29 2010 and is supported for 5 years (until 2015-04)

Comment: We don't know the purpose of this server. I read somewhere that PHP in 10.04 is somewhat dated for a LAMP server so there are tutorials to upgrade it to newer packages, but then you lose the advantages of LTS.

Comment: That's really quite questionable. There's almost no PHP applications that people actually use requiring PHP >5.2. RHEL/CentOS 5 is still distributing PHP 5.1.4, so most of the apps with any substantial penetration are still targeting that release.

Answer (score 0):

Im always using LTS ubuntu servers, less admin overhead for updates.
You can always if you decide upgrade release to 10.10..